# CETAS times out for large tables in Synapse Serverless SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a new external table using CETAS (`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT * FROM <table>`) statement from an already existing external table in Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool. The table I'm selecting from is a very large external table built on around 30 GB of data in parquet format stored in ADLS Gen 2 storage but the query always times out after about 30 minutes. I've tried using premium storage and also tried out most if not all the suggestions made [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/425867/query-timeout-expired-synapse-serverless-built-in.html) as well but it didn't help and the query still times out.
The error I get in Synapse Studio is :-

`Statement ID: {550AF4B4-0F2F-474C-A502-6D29BAC1C558} | Query hash: 0x2FA8C2EFADC713D | Distributed request ID: {CC78C7FD-ED10-4CEF-ABB6-56A3D4212A5E}. Total size of data scanned is 0 megabytes, total size of data moved is 0 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes. Query timeout expired.`

The core use case is that assuming I only have the external table name, I want to create a copy of the data over which that external table is created in Azure storage itself.

Is there a way to resolve this timeout issue or a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: What tool are you using to run the query?  How long does it take to timeout?  What exactly is the error message?

Comment: I've tried using Synapse Studio and DBeaver (JDBC). The query always times out after 30 minutes. The error message I get is `Statement ID: {550AF4B4-0F2F-474C-A502-6D29BAC1C558} | Query hash: 0x2FA8C2EFADC713D | Distributed request ID: {CC78C7FD-ED10-4CEF-ABB6-56A3D4212A5E}. Total size of data scanned is 0 megabytes, total size of data moved is 0 megabytes, total size of data written is 0 megabytes. Query timeout expired.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Serverless.

> **Query timeout expired**
>
> The error Query timeout expired is returned if the query executed more
> than 30 minutes on serverless SQL pool. This is a limit of serverless
> SQL pool that cannot be changed. Try to optimize your query by
> applying best practices, or try to materialize parts of your queries
> using CETAS. Check is there a concurrent workload running on the
> serverless pool because the other queries might take the resources. In
> that case you might split the workload on multiple workspaces.

[Self-help for serverless SQL pool - Query Timeout Expired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#query-timeout-expired)

> The core use case is that assuming I only have the external table name, I want to create a copy of the data over which that external table is created in Azure storage itself.

It's simple to do in a Data Factory copy job, a Spark job, or AzCopy.